# how to select data from oracle db and insert same data in mysql using node js? so far i am usung below code but its not working

Tags: node.js

I am trying to contain query result in **results** and pass into insert section for mysql. but its failing with below reason. May be I am missing something in the code itself.

```
connection.query("INSERT INTO authdetails (total, authcli, authuser) VALUES ?",\[results\], function(err, rows) {
^
ReferenceError: results is not defined
```

```
var config = require('/config.json');
var dbhost = config.host;
var service_name = config.service_name;
var user = config.user;
var password = config.password;

const getQueryOracle = async(ip, Service_NAME, user, password, query) =\> {
try {
sql = await oracledb.getConnection({
connectString: `${ip}/${Service_NAME}`,
user: user,
password: password
})
results = await sql.execute(query),
} catch(err) {
console.error(err.message);
} finally {
if(sql) {
try {
// Always close connections
await sql.close()
} catch (err) {
console.error(err.message)
}
}
return results:
}

};

const mysql = require('/mysql');
const connection = mysql.createConnection({
host: 'localhost',
port: 3306,
user: 'testuser',
password: 'testusera123',
database: 'DashBoard'
});

connection.query("INSERT INTO authdetails (total, authcli, authuser) VALUES ?", \[results\], function (err, rows) {
if (err) {
console.log(err);
connection.commit();
connection.close();
return;
}

    getQueryOracle(dbhost, service_name, user, password,
        `myquery`
    )

})
```

Comment: `results` is only defined within your `try/catch` clause. it doesn't exist outside of that context, so it can't be returned.

Comment: @pmdba, thanks for letting me know, can you please let me how can i achieve my requirement. i have tried but still its not working,